# Error that numpy library import is not available?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, spyder

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
```

Why am I getting a warning next to both of these lines "unable to detect undefined names"

Answer (score 0):

Because numpy module don't come with python standard library. you should first install numpy by using python pakage manager : pip 
if you are in windows then you can run following command in cmd
pip install numpy
to install numpy and then you can import in your python file

Comment: same with pylab or matplot lib module

Comment: Thanks.What's the code I should write in anaconda prompt? or should I use the py exe ?

Comment: Also when I run simple functions like plot and np.arange how are they working if it is not installed ?